# using distinct on single table column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am selecting data from 3 tables [2 tables with a relational table in between them] The below image is a screenshot of the result

[image]

Is there a way in which i can apply DISTINCT on certain columns such that i can get the results as below? NB// i have edited the below image
  [image]

Below is my sql code

Comment: please paste results as text,it allows some one to copy and test

Comment: Please show the query as well as Image

Comment: Add sample table data, and the expected result - all as formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: The answer is no, distinct is a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows.

Comment: Are you using a language like PHP to display the results of the query? If so, you can use it to test if the values in a column are the same as the previous row, and display them as blanks instead.

Comment: It's possible to do it in MySQL using user-defined variables, but it's more complicated, so if you can do it in a real programming language you're better off.

Comment: Yeah, i am using php

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't apply distinct on single column unless, you are pulling just one column from table.

Distinct applies on complete row. It will get you unique rows in table